# Why use `javascript:void(0)` instead of `javascript:` as an href do nothing placeholder?

Tags: javascript, html, href, placeholder

I have seen `href="javascript:void(0)"` and I have seen `href="javascript:;"`  Is there any reason I would not just use `href="javascript:"` instead?

**Edit:** Let me make it clear: I am combining this with an `onclick` and have no objection to using `return false` if it becomes necessary to use the alternative. Of course this is only if the alternative makes better sense over `javascript:`.

<strike>Also, **I have yet to see a answer to my question shown (clearly I think) in the first paragraph.**</strike> Thanks, david. :)

> I have seen `href="javascript:void(0)"` and I have seen `href="javascript:;"`  Is there any reason I would not just use `href="javascript:"` instead?

Comment: How often do you see URLs with just `http:`? I suspect it's because standards mandate that when a protocol or href type is announced, you need to put something after it! :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0 - about the same topic, may be helpfull

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666683/href-javascript-vs-href-javascriptvoid0

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Doesn't answer you question but may shed a bit more light on it, some early versions of browsers like netscape had problems when a script was used within the `href`.

The `void` operator was pretty much to only way force the click to do nothing.

Now, with browsers properly implementing "pseudo URLs", you can safely just use `javascript:;`.

Comment: `javascript:;` why not `javascript:`?

Comment: I'm seeing HTAs (IE7 mode) opening `href="javascript;;"` in a new window.

Answer (score 18):

Personally I'd avoid using either. I'd have `onclick='return false;'` instead, and just set `href='#'`.

Why? Because if you put Javascript code in the href, then it appears in the browser's status bar when you hover over the link, just like any other URL. It just looks messy.

In fact, since it's going to be ignored anyway, you could put any URL you fancy into the `href`, not just a hash. The hash is safest, just in case your user has Javascript disabled, but aside from that point, it could be anything.

But I have to point out: having an `<a>` tag with the href going to a void Javascript code seems to rather defeat the point of having an `<a>` tag in the first place. I can see how you'd want to enable and disable a link at runtime, but simply setting the href to void does seem somewhat pointless. If it isn't going to be a real link, why not just have a `<span>` or some other tag. If you must make it look like a link, it's trivial to do that in CSS.

Comment: The hash symbol is meant to be used as an anchor rather than for this purpose. You will get undesirable effects from time to time when you use it this way such as your page jumping all over the place.

Comment: @RubyFanatic - to be pedantic about it, the hash symbol is a *link to an anchor*, but I accept your point. I don't agree though; as long as Javacript is enabled, you won't get undesirable effects, and even if you do, jumping to the top of the current page is rarely a disaster. Besides, the hash symbol has been completely usurped for use with Ajax functionality now, to the point that it's actually recommended as good practice, so doing this will hardly be going against the grain.

Comment: Just to answer your question: I don't use span because then it does not work with the keyboard and does not automatically get blue/underline/pointer on the CSS.

Comment: well actually. If you have a `tabindex="0"` on your span, then it would react to :focus events. i've tried this example in IE 7, 8 and other newer browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/vptB3/1/ (IE doesn't support :focus anyway)

Answer (score 2):

The ideal situation is to not put any code on the element itself, but rather use javascript in either a script tag, or in an external file and bind the event handler there.

Comment: Yes. Javascript event binding on the hyperlink should produce the most readable code and easy to maintain for the future.

Answer (score 1):

It's better not to use either. The `href` attribute indicates a url. It's better to use event handlers to get the desired behaviour, which is probably the `onclick` event.

In this case the desired behaviour apparently is to do nothing. Firstly, why use an anchor tag at all when it doesn't link anywhere? Secondly, this can be handles by preventing event bubbling, by letting the `onclick` event handler return `false`. Then the `href` can either point to `#`, or better even to have it point to a url that more or less has the same effect as the event handler, so it will degrade gracefully when javascript is turned off.

Comment: If JavaScript is turned off there will be a big red `noscript` warning on top. Also, I do not see how it is better for the status bar to have a URL instead of the work javascript.

Comment: Correction: "word" JavaScript

Comment: @GeorgeBailey I'm impressed you come back 5 months later to correct a typo. +1

Comment: How about when you need to **apply the anchor styles to something** that "does not link anywhere" but executes a Javascript script that you don't want to expose to the browser's status bar?