# why use javascrpit:void(0) other than javascript:; in href attributes?

Tags: javascript, href

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why use `javascript:void(0)` instead of `javascript:` as an href do nothing placeholder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237105/why-use-javascriptvoid0-instead-of-javascript-as-an-href-do-nothing-plac)

It seems we can achieve the same result using `javascript:;` while saving 7 characters. Why it is always recommended to use `javascript:void(0)`?

Comment: One more related: [Href attribute for JavaScript links: “#” or “javascript:void(0)”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0)

Comment: My bad. I didn't get it in the search result. @Sudhir Thank you!