# two divs same class, get title only of THIS div

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I thought this would be easy but I'm stuck and can't find a solution.  I have two divs, both same class.  The difference is the content inside each one.  I'm trying to get the text and values from each but the output is from both of them.  I have an image and when it's clicked, I want to get the value from THIS div where the image is located.  Here's my code:

```
<div class="mainSelect">
    <h1>I am Title</h1><br>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="clickme"><img class="pic" src="img/img.png"/></a>
</div>
<div class="mainSelect">
    <h1>I am Second Title</h1><br>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="clickme"><img class="pic" src="img/img.png"/></a>
</div>
```

And in javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".clickme").click(function(){
        var t = $("h1").text();
        alert (t);
    });
});
```

When I do it this way, I get "I am Title I am Second Title".  Is there a global way to only display the title of the div where the image was clicked?

Comment: As a side remark, you shouldn't have multiple h1 tags in the same page, that's not semantically correct.

Comment: you don't need a `br` after `h1` since it's a block element (if you need spacing use `CSS`)

Comment: also, you might wanna change `href` to `#` and `return false` at the end of the click handler.

Comment: The reason why I have "javascript:void(0)" is because it doesn't add a hash...to me it looks cleaner and the .click function still works.  Can you explain or give me a link to what the difference is?  Or why it would be problematic?

Comment: @user2025469 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498492/javascriptvoid0-vs-return-false-vs-preventdefault and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237105/why-use-javascriptvoid0-instead-of-javascript-as-an-href-do-nothing-plac

Comment: If the `a` doesn't really have the purpose and semantic value of an `anchor` you can simply remove it and attach the clickme class and handler to the `img` itself and it will prevent the hash being appended to the url. `cursor: pointer` CSS on it will display the hand cursor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `this`:

`var t = $(this).siblings('h1').text();`

Comment: Thanks, that's the one I'll use.  It works and @billyonecan explained about traversing up and down the DOM tree.  Waiting to accept it...

Comment: you can also use `$(this).prev()` if you remove the `br` and can guarantee that the `h1` will always come before the `a.clickme`

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".clickme").click(function(){
        var t = $(this).closest(".mainSelect").find("h1").text();
        alert (t);
    });
});
```

use `this` selector, then find `h1` in its parent.

Comment: You right, better use `sibling`. But I saw there's someone had answer with `sibling` so I just want to provide another approach. About `parent`. It's safer to use `closest`, because if I remember right, parent don't stop right at the first element that match your criteria but it will go up further.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".clickme").click(function(){
        var t = $(this).closest('.mainSelect').children('h1').text();
        alert (t);
 });
```