# Is this href value equivalent to "javascript:void(0)"?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between `javascript://` and `javascript:void(0)` ?

```
<a href="javascript://" class="button toggle-filters">Filters</a>
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666683/href-javascript-vs-href-javascriptvoid0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previous two answers cover the direct answer to your question, but on a separate track I think you should consider using neither of them. Assuming you're using the anchor tag to illustrate to the user that there's an action they can take by clicking on that text, there are multiple mechanisms for illustrating that, and semantically an anchor tag should illustrate a destination, not an activity.

See [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0/134957#134957), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842953/or-javascriptvoid0/4842962#4842962).

Answer (score 2):

`javascript://` runs JavaScript that has no statements

`javascript:void(0)` runs JavaScript that evaluates the statement `0` and then returns `undefined`.

so `javascript://` is much similar to `javascript:;`

[Neither should be used.](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/#build)

Comment: and if i was going to use any of the above i would use `javascript:;`