# custom pager return for jquery cycle using Modulus

Tags: javascript, jquery, operators, cycle, modulus

Trying to get this custom pager to work for jQuery Cycle.

I want the `pagerAnchorBuilder` to return a `list` item every 5 images so later on I can turn the pager into it's own cycle.

Here's the code:

```
  pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx,slide){
        var $slideCount = $('#ul-homecycle > li').length; 
            if ((idx==0) || (idx%5 === 0)){
                return '<li><a href="javascript:setSlide('+ idx +')" class="transhover"><img src="../images/home/thumb_carousel' + idx + '.jpg" width="183" height="72" /></a></li>';
            }
            else{ 
                return '<a href="javascript:setSlide('+ idx +')" class="transhover"><img src="../images/home/thumb_carousel' + idx + '.jpg" width="183" height="72" /></a>';

            }
    }
```

So in the end I want Cycle to return this:

```
<ul>
<li>
<a href="javascript:void(0);">derp</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);">derp</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);">derp</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);">derp</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);">derp</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="javascript:void(0);">derp</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);">derp</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);">derp</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);">derp</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);">derp</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Please disregard the `setSlide(#)` and the class values from the HTML string return in the JS, I have that under control. I can't figure this out even after 2 hours of searching.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dude, don't use href="javascript:.." use onclick=""

Comment: According to this post javascript:void is preferred: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666683/href-javascript-vs-href-javascriptvoid0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out. Here's the modified code, commented for your convenience:

```
function cycles(){
    //Activate main slide with proper pager/carousel container.
    $('#ul-homecycle').after('<div id="homecycle-carousel-container"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="btn-homecycle-prev" class="transhover"></a><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="btn-homecycle-next" class="transhover"></a><ul id="homecycle-carousel">').cycle({
        timeout: 7000,
        speed: 500,
        sync: true,
        fx: 'fade',
        fit: 0,
        startingSlide: 2,
        activePagerClass:'active',
        slideResize: 0,
        pager:  '#homecycle-carousel',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx,slide){
            return '<a href="javascript:setSlide('+ idx +')" class="transhover"><img src="../images/home/thumb_carousel' + idx + '.jpg" width="183" height="72" /></a>';
        },
        // Build pager that automagically hightlights updated pager thumb and also continue to next pager slide if the next thumb isn't visible
        updateActivePagerLink: function(pager, activeIndex) { 
            $(pager).find('a').not(':eq('+activeIndex+')').removeClass('active').children('img').fadeTo(200,.5)
            $(pager).find('a:eq('+activeIndex+')').addClass('active').children('img').fadeTo(200, 1); 

            //If next slide in carousel is hidden then go to next carousel slide
            if ($(pager).find('a:eq('+activeIndex+')').parent('li').css('display') == "none"){
                $('#homecycle-carousel').cycle('next');
            }
        }
    });
        //Before building the carousel wrap an Li around every 5 thumbs    
        $('#homecycle-carousel > a').each(function(i) {
           var a = $('#homecycle-carousel > a');
            for( var i = 0; i < a.length; i+=5 ) {
                a.slice(i, i+5).wrapAll('<li></li>');
            }
        });
        //Now that we have Lis wrapped around every 5 thumbs, initiate new cycle    
        $('#homecycle-carousel').cycle({
            easing: 'easeOutSine',
            prev: '#btn-homecycle-prev',
            next: '#btn-homecycle-next',
            slideExpr: 'li',
            activePagerClass:'active',
            timeout:0,
            speed: 500,
            fx: 'scrollHorz'
        });
        //Artifically activate new thumb 
        $('#homecycle-carousel li a').click(function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){
            $('#homecycle-carousel li a').not(this).removeClass('active').children('img').fadeTo(200,.5);
            $(this).addClass('active').children('img').fadeTo(200,1);
        }
        });

}
```