# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) after successful ajax post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When i click on the element `<a class="page-number" href="javascript:void();">1</a>` 
The server side code is executed without errors.
At the client side i get the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

The Jquery code is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".page-number").click(function () {
                var page = parseInt($(this).html());

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("ProductsList")',
                    data: { "page": page },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#products-list").html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

What is wrong with that?

[image]

After trying to isolate the issue i noticed that the exception is raised within the ajax callback

[image]

Comment: What line is associated to this error?

Comment: @Stubborn can you check the update?

Comment: why you need javascript:void(); in href...did you try without using that ..?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666683/href-javascript-vs-href-javascriptvoid0

Comment: @damitj07 If i omit that, after the ajax response, i get a reload of the webpage.

Comment: Please try javascript:void(0) or you can do a event.preventDefault() on the click function....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be the [`void()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void). It requires a parameter. Try using `void(0)`